# On Telerik RadScheduleView silverlight control, all day events are not showing on Monday

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radscheduleview

I'm using the Telerik RadScheduleView silverlight control. (Silverlight 4.0. Telerik Q2 2011)

When I set the WeekViewDefination to show the all day area, and also have a day start time set, the all day area appears as expected, but any all day events on Monday are not visible (the all day area appears, but Monday is blank.)

```
<telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
    <telerik:WeekViewDefinition DayStartTime="08:00" DayEndTime="18:00" ShowAllDayArea="True"/>
    <telerik:MonthViewDefinition/>
</telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
```

The appointments definitely exist in the AppointmentsSource as they are visible on the MonthView.

If I remove the DayStartTime/DayEndTime values, the all day appointments on the Monday become visible.

On the left of the screen shot is the day view with nothing visible in the all day area, on the right is the month view which shows the all day appointments that exist.
[image]

In this example, specifically the appointments that are not appearing are ones that are set to recur daily, and the start/end times are set to 01:00:00 to 02:00:00. I have also tried this with single appointments and seem to have the same problem.

I've tried the Telerik forums but didn't get an answer.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik have confirmed that this is a bug.

It has been logged in their bug tracking system: [Issue ID 7525 - All day area is not working correct when Start/End time is set](http://www.telerik.com/support/pits.aspx#/public/silverlight/7525)